# Not Able to use environment variable in React project

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, dotenv, yarn-v2

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'D:\MERS\NextJS\youtube\node_modules\dotenv\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

Comment: Please include more details, such as what you are trying to do and the code that produces the error.